# move_uploaded_file failure

Tags: php, image

Can someone help me understand why this is returning false?

```
if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field]['tmp_name'], $path))) {
```

As in, potential causes. I have checked the variables are correct and I have checked permissions on the destination folder which is 777.

Cheers!

For those wanting to see var_dump ($_FILES);

```
array(1) { ["image"]=>  array(5) { ["name"]=>  string(14) "accountile.png" 
["type"]=>  string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=>  string(14) "/tmp/php28IQhv" 
["error"]=>  int(0) ["size"]=>  int(394) } }
```

Comment: My first thought would be to ask whether $field is set correctly, i.e. whether you are specifying a correct path name.  I would then ask the same for $path.  Try var_dumping each of them.

Comment: For those with Avast installed can checkout this answer: <https://stackoverflow.com/a/59223789/10539212>

Comment: For me it was wrong path , it's very important to 100% check your path existing on the server or not , I put the path according to local server paths when I upload it to remote server I got this error .

Answer (score 26):

> I have checked the variables

Do not check variables but **check error messages.**
It's the only thing you need.
Add these lines at the top of your code

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and see what it says.
If move_uploaded_file failed, it will **always** raise an error with **detailed explanation**.
You won't believe it, but reading error messages is way more efficient way to find a problem than *guesswork* you tried before

I can't believe noone mentioned it already.

Comment: Good to know, I've never had problems with move_uploaded_file so I've never needed to know.

Comment: Error/fail when `move_uploaded_file()` is most likely caused by permission problem in destination folder/directory. And yes, you can see the error messages with this answers to check the error messages rather than checking variables for errors.

Comment: While enabling the warnings is indeed a good approach, it's not true that `move_uploaded_file` always creates an error message. In particular, if `filename` does not point to a valid file, **no** warning is created. [The PHP manual states](https://php.net/manual/function.move-uploaded-file.php): _If `filename` is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and `move_uploaded_file()` will return `FALSE`._

Answer (score 1):

With `move_uploaded_file` you don't need 777 permissions.  What is the output of `$path`?  Have you verified that `$path` exists?  Have you verified that `$field` exists?

Either $field or $path don't exist, or open_basedir is in effect is my guess.

Is `open_basedir` restriction enabled?  That could prevent the destination of the uploaded file from being written to.  Look in your php.ini for `open_basedir`, if there's a path specified then it is enabled and you want to see if the destination path of your uploaded file is within this path.  If it is, that's why it's failing.

**update**

$path cannot be a URL, it must be a local path such as `/home/user/public_html/`

Comment: $path and $field return expected strings. I can post the most recent output if it'll help.

Comment: @Yoi you are aware that $path needs to be a file name, not a path, right?

Comment: open_basedir has no value in phpinfo

Comment: $path = http://www.barbadostravelbuddy.co.uk/demo/images/carhire/accountile10420103260403000000pm.png most recently

Answer (score 1):

Don't use

```
$path = "http://www.barbadostravelbuddy.co.uk/demo/images/carhire
    /accountile10420103260403000000pm.png"
```

but

```
$path = "/home/sites/barbadostravelbuddy.co.uk/public_html/demo/images/carhire/
    accountile10420103260403000000pm.png"
```

It needs to be a path on the system, not an URL.

Comment: I tried /public_html/demo/images/carhire which hasn't worked. My directory struture is root > public_html > demo > images > carhire

Comment: Ok. Try to do a mkdir (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) in that directory. That will check that the directory is correct and that you have rights on it.

Comment: Then you either don't have the right or your path is not correct. Can you do a phpinfo() and give us the `_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` ? Can you give us the permissions the directory has ?

Comment: document_root is     /home/sites/barbadostravelbuddy.co.uk/public_html/ and permission is 755

Comment: Then why did you tell "My directory struture is root > public_html > demo > images > carhire" ? It's not... Answer updated with correct path.

Answer (score 1):

Did you edit your php.ini to make sure upload_tmp_dir points to a temporary directory?

Answer (score 1):

Check:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Inside the form itself, without it file upload won't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Basic debugging steps:

- What does a `print_r($_FILES)` look like?
- Does the source file actually exist?
- Is the "error" flag of the file upload zero (will be visible when doing the print_r)
- What does the target `$path` look like?
- Are you specifying a full file name in the target path?

My guess is that `$path` is only a path to a folder, not to a full file name.

> Update: You need to specify a **filesystem path** as $path.

Comment: All of those are as they should be (I assume you mean an absolute target path)

Comment: @YsoL8 `$path` needs to be a full file name that doesn't exist yet, not only a path to a directory.

Comment: $path = http://www.barbadostravelbuddy.co.uk/demo/images/carhire/accountile10420103260403000000pm.png most recently

Answer (score 0):

Did you check permission on the temporary upload folder?

What does php tell you if you do:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loïc Février, thank you, you've saved me a lot of time!

Here is my part...
printing possible errors during upload.

First create directory Uploader/UploadedFiles
Then use code below...

```
$destination=$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/Uploader/UploadedFiles/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],  $destination)){
   echo ("Stored in".$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/Uploader/UploadedFiles/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}else{
   $html_body = '<h1>File upload error!</h1>';
   switch ($_FILES[0]['error']) {
   case 1:
      $html_body .= 'The file is bigger than this PHP installation allows';
      break;
   case 2:
      $html_body .= 'The file is bigger than this form allows';
      break;
   case 3:
      $html_body .= 'Only part of the file was uploaded';
      break;
   case 4:
      $html_body .= 'No file was uploaded';
      break;
   default:
      $html_body .= 'unknown errror';
   } 
   echo ($html_body);
}
```

Comment: Using $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT] fixed it for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

`$path` has to be a file name and not a path to a directory.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem.

If your error says *"Failed to open stream: Permission Denied"* it means the **PHP Server** is not being capable of creating the new file inside your destination directory.

Once you have set the Linux permissions on the directory (wich sounds like you did by making it 777) you should give that special permission to the PHP Server.

If your folder is named "uploads", you should cd to the previous directory and use the next command:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t uploads
```

That definetly solved my problem.

Hope it helps.